# Linked list not showing proper data

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm learning on linked list so decided to do some exercise here I'm trying to show the data entered in the list. I've also include a comment for my understanding on the line

```
typedef struct node {
    int num;
    struct node *nextptr;
}Node;

Node *stnode;
void createNodeList(int n);
void displayList();
```

This are my created Node

```
void createNodeList(int n) {
    Node *tmp;
    int num = 1;

    //allocate memory address to stnode
    Node *stnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if (stnode == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error");
    }
    else {
        printf("Input data for node 1:");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        //declare the stnode num field in struct as user input
        stnode->num = num;
        //declare the stnode address of the next node NULL (to be the last node)
        stnode->nextptr = NULL;
        //define the node name as tmp
        tmp = stnode;

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            //allocate node to fnNode
            Node *fnNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            if (fnNode == NULL) {
                printf("Memory can not be allocated");
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("Input data for node %d: ", i);
                scanf("%d", &num);

                //declare the node name fnNode num to store user input
                fnNode->num = num;
                //link the fnNode of nextptr to address null
                fnNode->nextptr = NULL;
                //link tmp node to fnNode
                tmp->nextptr = fnNode;

                tmp = tmp->nextptr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is to display them

```
void displayList() {
    Node *tmp;
    if (stnode == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty");
    }
    else {
        tmp = stnode;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            printf("Data = %d\n", tmp->num);
            tmp = tmp->nextptr;
        }
    }
}
```

After I've input 3 data, it should show the data I've input.

But it show "List is empty"

Thank you =)

Comment: It show "List is empty", after I've already input data inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Node *stnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

By this you are shadowing the global variable. That's why you retain no changes in the global variable. All you have done is used a local variable with same name as that of the global variable `stNode`.

That line should be

```
stnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

<sub>Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. It should be</sub>

```
stnode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

Or even more clearly

```
stnode = malloc(sizeof *stnode);
```

> <sub>If you compile this program with `-Wshadow` option then you will
>   get warning regarding this shadowing. Enable all compiler warnings. It
>   helps.</sub>

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. So my mistake was declaring two stnode?
Also is my understanding thru comment done correctly?

Comment: @Gaming.: Yes. You have declared a variable with the same name as in global scope. That's why the local scope was used shadowing the global one.